# Adding search functionality in select options using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add search functionality in the select form using bootstrap. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

  <title>Depots list</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap-select CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./css/st.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 </head>



<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
                  <form>
                   <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Country</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" placeholder="" data-live-search="true">
                        <options>China</options>
                        <options>Malaysia</options>
                        <options>Singapore</options>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div><!-- /.box -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I have problem with contradiction between **form-control** and **selectpicker** classes in select form. My code works only for **form-control** class.

For selection searches I have used this: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search

My question is: How can I use both of the **form-control** and **selectpicker** classes in select tag? I have used normal procedure to write the class name with a space. But it seems not to work.

Comment: whats the problem?? what is not working as expected?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get a search functionality you must set the `data-tokens` attribute for each options. Here is your code after adding it. Let me know if you need additional help.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Country</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" data-live-search="true">
                <option data-tokens="china">China</option>
  <option data-tokens="malayasia">Malayasia</option>
  <option data-tokens="singapore">Singapore</option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved by using data-tokens. Plus, some of the problems i have faced is due to some browser issues.

Comment: I'm using the dynamic list and search box is also not coming in the dropdown. I have added data-tokens too still it is not working

Answer (score 7):

Multi Selection Form and searchable

```js
$(function() {
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script>
  $(function () {
   $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
   });
   $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
    var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
    var message = "";
    selected.each(function () {
     message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">
     <form action="#" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country lstFruits" multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true">
         <option data-tokens="china">China</option>
         <option data-tokens="malayasia">Malayasia</option>
         <option data-tokens="singapore">Singapore</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```html
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />

<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
<option data-tokens="name">name</option>
<option data-tokens="family">family</option>
</select>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Search Box in Select Option in Asp.net Core#
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

-At View Page
 <select id="empselect" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" asp-for="EmpId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.empInilistvb,"EmpId", "EmpInitial"))"></select>
```

I think `data-token=` is not mandatory attribute.

I used Search Box in Select Option in Asp.net Core.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an HTML attribute into the select tag if you are using the bootstrap selectpicker and initialize it on your script.

> data-live-search="true"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.classname').selectpicker();
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this very simple JS it works wonders

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  </head>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
      <p>This uses <a href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/">https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/</a></p>
      <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
        <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
        <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
        <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
        <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
      </select>
      <span class="help-inline">With <code>data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"</code>. Try searching for california</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

This uses https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/