# Getting value from bootstrap search dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, search, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm using the following code to make a dropdown that can be searched. (I followed this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005249/adding-search-functionality-in-select-options-using-bootstrap)).

How would I go about getting the value of the selected option, i.e. if they select China `var country ='CN'`?

So far I have tried various things, with no success, most things return 'US'. I imagine this is because it is the top option in the dropdown.

```
Country: 
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" data-live-search="true">
    <option disabled>Select a Country</option>
    <option data-tokens="United States" value="US">United States</option>
    <option data-tokens="United Kingdom" value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-tokens="China" value="CN">China</option>
    <option data-tokens="Japan" value="JP">Japan</option>
  </select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"></link>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bootstrap-4]... it appears that you're using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate selector:

```js
$('div').click(() => {
  console.log($('#select-country > option:checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" data-live-search="true">
    <option disabled>Select a Country</option>
    <option data-tokens="United States" value="US">United States</option>
    <option data-tokens="United Kingdom" value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-tokens="China" value="CN">China</option>
    <option data-tokens="Japan" value="JP">Japan</option>
  </select>
  <div>click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select-country').change(function() {
 console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" data-live-search="true">
    <option disabled>Select a Country</option>
    <option data-tokens="United States" value="US">United States</option>
    <option data-tokens="United Kingdom" value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-tokens="China" value="CN">China</option>
    <option data-tokens="Japan" value="JP">Japan</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(() => {
      alert($('#select-country > option:checked').val());
    });});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score -1):

try this
I have saved the working code here you can run
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPQ4HAHW1ZUE