# Bootstrap select with search option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a dropdownlist with search in bootstrap.

```
<select  class="form-control selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" >
</select>
```

When i run the page i see that two select was generated like as the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiPjk.png)

Comment: Which version of bootstrap

Comment: This question has been answer here:: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005249/adding-search-functionality-in-select-options-using-bootstrap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Bootstrap Version 3

Comment: The problem is not the same. My problem consist in the fact of that work but it generate two select. In his case it not work.

Comment: You will need to share more of your code: How you're including support for Bootstrap Select, what your JavaScript initialization looks like, etc.